# User Java class in the Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I have Java class which initialized with data from file. The init process is slow. Is is possible to move this initialization to NDK level? Is it possible to create my user defined class in NDK and return it into SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but depending on the exact nature of the data and the class, it might not gain you any speed.

You'd need to provide more data for me to give you more specific help. There might be a better way to structure your class(es), or a better way to store the data, for example.

One general suggestion that I can make is that you run the Android profiling tools to see where your bottleneck is: It might be something obvious that you can fix in a few lines in Java.